# How to trigger a specific task inside a DAG using the airflow's REST API?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a DAG with multiple tasks and would only like to trigger a specific task instead of all tasks at a time using airflow's REST API. Is it possible?

For Example:
I have a DAG named: DAG_0001 with Tasks:

export_task_0001, upload_task_0001, run_task_0001
export_task_0002, upload_task_0002, run_task_0002
export_task_0003, upload_task_0003, run_task_0003

export_task : exports data from ES
upload_task : uploads data to web services such as azure or aws
run_task    : runs the task

Now, i would like to trigger only task_0002 instead of all the tasks in the DAG_0001. Is it possible to do it? If not is there an alternate or best possible solution?

Currently, i could only trigger entire DAG, but could not trigger specific task.

Comment: Is there any reason for just task_0002 executes? I think the anwser for your question depends on the condition why just tasks 0002 should be executed. Could you please describe in more details why just task_0002 should be executed?

Comment: Mostly to have control over the DAG and its tasks. And also, incase only task_0002 fails among all the others. Then instead of triggering the entire DAG which would trigger all tasks, I would only want that failed task to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Correct Airflow Rest API triggers the whole DAG.
So the obvious and faster solution would be to create a separate DAG per task.

One alternative if you have access to the airflow host you can execute a specific task by executing:
`airflow tasks run DAG_0001 run_task_0002 execution_date_or_run_id`
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#tasks

Lastly,
If you really need to use RestAPI and target a task
you can add an if clause and check if the task_to_execute is set and if the value is the same as the task name:
e.g.

```
export_task_0001 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='export_task_0001',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=export_task,
    templates_dict={'task_to_execute': '{{ dag_run.conf["task_to_execute"] }}' },
    dag=dag
)

def export_task(**context):
    task_instance = context['task_instance']
    task_id = task_instance.task_id
    task_to_execute = context.get("templates_dict", {}).get('task_to_execute')

    if not task_to_execute or task_id == task_to_execute:
        print(f'Executing task: {task_id}')
        # Insert the logic of your task here
    else:
        print(f'Skipping task: {task_id}')
```

Then you can set the task_to_execute in your curl request as following:

```
 curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dags/dag_0001/dagRuns" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "conf": {
    "task_to_execute": "task_0002", 
  }
}'
```

Now the hackiest way, if you do not want to change your dag code, is to do something like:
Trigger the whole DAG but then manually set all other tasks [to a 'success' state.](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/patch_task_instance) For the task you want to run, you set its state to 'none'.Of course, this is not ideal because you are manipulating the task states.

Comment: Thank you, i will try the above solution. Not sure i'd want to try the hackiest way, as i want to automate the process instead of manually setting the states to 'none' or 'success'.

Comment: I would try to work eith the "retry" airflow parameter. Otherwise, you could implement the @alexpoulos7 solution in a python method and call it automatically using "on_failure_callback" or you could create a task as the last task in your dag with trigger_rule "one_failed". You could implement the clear task instance endpoint (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_clear_task_instances)